# How to change list display name in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: list, workflow

I want to change the column headings in my list, such as **Permit ID, Name of Applicant** etc:

[image]

Through this method - Go to **List tab** in the top ribbon > List settings > Click on a column name to edit:

[image]

[image]

Will this method affect the entire existing workflow? Or is it safe to change the UI this way?

Comment: Does your workflow depend on the column names?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the Set-SPUser CmdLet in PowerShell as below:

Set-SPUser -Identity 'domain\jsmith' -DisplayName 'John Smith' –Web http://WebApp:Port

For more information, please refer to the article

[How to change the Display Name in SharePoint 2010](https://sdelisle.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/how-to-change-the-display-name-in-sharepoint-2010/)

[How to update user display name in SharePoint](http://itgroove.net/stellark/2016/07/06/how-to-update-user-display-name-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: So will doing that change affect the workflow? All I want is to change the UI display name, not the internal name. I'm referring to changing from the List settings btw